# Need to double click on Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, ripple

I have my code:

```
+function($) {
'use strict';
var Ripple = function(element) {
    var $this = $(this)
    $(element).on('mousedown', $this.start)
}
Ripple.prototype.start = function(e) {
    var $this = $(this)
    var r = $this.find('.ripple-wave')
    if(r.length == 0) {
        $this.prepend('<div class="ripple-wave"></div>')
        r = $this.find('.ripple-wave')
    }
    if($this.hasClass('btn') || $this.hasClass('single-action')) {
        var posX = $(this).offset().left, posY = $(this).offset().top
        r.css('left', e.pageX - posX)
        r.css('top', e.pageY - posY)
    }
    r = r.parent()
    r.addClass('active')
    r.one('webkitAnimationEnd oanimationend msAnimationEnd animationend', function(e) {
        r.removeClass('active')
    })

}

var old = $.fn.ripple

$.fn.ripple = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        new Ripple(this)
    })
}

$.fn.ripple.Constructor = Ripple

$.fn.ripple.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.ripple = old
    return this
}}(jQuery);
```

But if i test on Mozilla Firefox, i have to double click the element in order to do its function.

I initialize this to my on page load using:

```
$('.ripple').ripple()
```

PS: I also have on click event on each element from other JS file.

In chrome, it's working properly, in a single click.

Comment: can you post the html to reproduce it?

Comment: don't think this solves your problem but shouldn't `$(element).on('mousedown', $this.start)` be `$(element).on('mousedown', this.start)`?

Comment: Can you please provide us with the full JQuery code, full html code, and possibly elaborate your prob a bit better?

Comment: it would be better if you can provide a jsFiddle to help debug :)

Answer (score 1):

1. `$( "p" ).dblclick(function() {
   alert( "Hello World!" );
   });`
2. `<p ondblclick="myFunction()">Double-click me</p>`

Comment: It is my comment to your deleted question.  Start to learn PHP. The main advantage is not that it is easy than C++. The main advantage is that it provides good job opportunities compared with C++. C++ programmers are required nowhere.